# Eager loading multiple tables with a conditional on only one in ActiveRecord

Tags: activerecord

```
published = Activity.all.eager_load([:podcast, :blog, :chat]).select('podcasts.draft = false')
```

I expect this code to output all podcasts which are not drafts, as well as all the blogs and chats. Instead it outputs everything.

Answer (score 0):

Use `where` if you want to filter ungrouped records:

```
published = Activity.where('podcasts.draft = false').eager_load([:podcast, :blog, :chat])
```